# NSArray not loading all the objects in the array?

Tags: ios, nsarray, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently subclassing a UICollectionViewCell and I have it loading the cells within an array (Below is the code inside the collectionViewCell.m):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        NSArray *cellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"insightCell" owner:self options:nil];
NSLog (@"NSArray cellArray %i", [cellArray count]);
 if ([cellArray count] < 1) {
            return nil;
        }
        if (![[cellArray objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
            return nil;
        }
        self = [cellArray objectAtIndex:0];
 }
return self;

}
```

That all loads fine and it displays the return value I have in my `- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method, which is 11. But when I log the initiation process of the cellArray this is what it looks like:

[image: App Log data]

So the cell array is counting how many times the array adds a cell and for some reason it only goes up to 6. The weird thing is; all 11 items load but the NSArray doesn't log that it's loaded all 11, it just stops at 6 which is annoying... I've tried a few different ways of fixing this but they don't seem to be working and it's driving me mad! I don't suppose anyone else has come across this issue?

I'll add in my rootController.m collectionview code just incase, however, it does all link up the proper way so this shouldn't be the problem.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";

    insightCell *myCell = (insightCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

return myCell;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have only 6 cells which is visible on your screen. And the others will be generated if you start scrolling.

Comment: Yeh I thought that but then when I do scroll it still doesn't add those cells into the log. It's almost as if, if I have more than 6 cells in the UICollectionView it doesn't register then extra 5...

Comment: That is exactly what the cell reusing pattern is supposed to do. There are not more cells (of a type/reuse id) kept in memory as there are visible on the screen at once. As soon as one of them is scrolled off completely it is made available for its reuse. Naturally its initWithWhatever method is not being called any more because it does exist already. Consequentially you should not place any business logic in the init method. Subclass the layoutSubViews or the cellForRowAtIndexPath methods to manage content and content-depending appearance.

Comment: As the code shown does what it is supposed to do - what do you intent to achieve? Why did you expect any different behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've only just started using UICollectionViews and connecting with web data so i've not come across this kind of issue before. I guess I was being a bit naive! Apologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you create the cell with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier it will reuse the cell with same id which is scrolled out from the screen.
See reference: [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a)

You can find a good presentation from the topic in the WWDC 2012 Videos.

Comment: Ahhh, yeh I see. Thats annoying. Thanks for pointing that out. Ok is there any way around this? A way to just add on cells in the array rather than reusing existing cells?

Comment: Don't use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Use [[insightCell alloc] init] instead. But This is not really good for you, because it creates unnecessary cells. What is the problem with resue?

Comment: Well I'm using server data. So I have data on the server which is contained within an items with an id. these "id's" were going to be assigned to the cells so that each cell would contain the data that matches the id from the server the end result would be displaying images which is part of the server items data. Reusing the cell means I get the first 6 items with their images fine but the remaining 5 don't display.